# Makefile overriding default implicit rule

Tags: c++, c, makefile

Why this rule cannot override the default implicit rule ?

When make is invoked like: `make myapp` (suppose myapp.c is there). The make runs the default command to build and link the program instead the commands defined in this implicit rule:

```
#... omitted code
LCUS=$(LIBS)/libcus.a

#... omitted code
% : %.o $(LCUS)
        echo  !!! Custom build !!!
        $(MY_CMD) $< -o $@ $(LCUS)
```

Comment: `defined in this implicit rule:`...did you mean `explicit`?

Comment: try `make -r` to disable all built-in rules, does it help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taken from the [GNU online `make` manual](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/make-3.79.1/html_chapter/make_10.html#SEC104):

> You can override a built-in implicit rule (or one you have defined
>   yourself) by defining a new pattern rule with the same target and
>   prerequisites, but different commands.

So I would assume it is because the prerequisites are not the same as the implicit rule.

Also take from the `make` manual:

> Linking a single object file `n` is made automatically from `n.o` by
>   running the linker (usually called `ld`) via the C compiler. The
>   precise command used is `$(CC) $(LDFLAGS) n.o $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS)`.
>   This rule does the right thing for a simple program with only one
>   source file. It will also do the right thing if there are multiple
>   object files (presumably coming from various other source files), one
>   of which has a name matching that of the executable file. Thus,
>
> ```
>  x: y.o z.o
> ```
>
> when `x.c`, `y.c` and `z.c` all exist will execute:
>
> ```
> cc -c x.c -o x.o
> cc -c y.c -o y.o
> cc -c z.c -o z.o
> cc x.o y.o z.o -o x
> rm -f x.o
> rm -f y.o
> rm -f z.o
> ```

So basically `make` understands implicit rules for program files that are generated from `.o` files but when you throw in your static library it doesn't understand.  A simple way to test would be to remove `$(LCUS)` from your dependencies (as a temporary measure) to see if it then uses your rule instead of the built in one.  If it does then you know that is your problem.  If simply adding `myapp` in replace of `%` is a problem because you want the rule to build multiple targets you can try the following:

```
$(APPS): % : %.o $(LCUS)
```

where `$(APPS)` is a variable containing all the applications you wish to build.  This will allow one rule to build multiple targets.  You could also skip the use of the variable altogether and place a space separated list.  This is an example of a static pattern rule, more information can be found [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-Usage.html#Static-Usage).  The difference between static pattern and implicit rules can be found [here.](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-versus-Implicit.html#Static-versus-Implicit)

Comment: Let me know if it works, also you can try my recommendation in my later edit.

Comment: Canceling the default rules, worked ! (%:%.c, %:%.o, %.o:%.c)

Answer (score 3):

Your rule isn't the same as the built-in implicit rule so it doesn't cancel it.

Additionally, make always prefers a rule that doesn't require intermediate files to be built to one that does. If you pre-create the `.a` file make might use your rule instead (but it might not even still).

If you cancel the built-in rule and leave your rule in place it should work correctly I believe.